# increasing post vars limit in php with suhosin is not working

Tags: php, post, max, limit, suhosin

I have large a form which have approx. 2000 inputs. Some inputs are mufti-dimensional array(4th Level Depth).

But my server does not allow more than 1120 post Vars. I have increased following parameters of suhosin and which have been increased successfully as per phpinfo. But still it does not allow more than 1120 vars. Any suggestion?

```
suhosin.request.max_vars = 30000
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length = 512
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length = 65535
suhosin.post.max_array_depth=256
suhosin.post.max_name_length=256
```

Comment: This may be useful: [php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/](http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/). It mentions extra php parameters that you are not setting. This may assist as well: [changing-the-max-allowed-post-variables/](http://dtbaker.net/web-development/changing-the-max-allowed-post-variables/)

Comment: Thanks for the links. As I mentioned I have already done this and my phpinfo() is showing updated values correctly. But still it does not allow more than 1120 vars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as Suhosin is concerned, you may have a look at various 'max'-options:

```
suhosin.post.max_array_depth
suhosin.post.max_array_index_length
suhosin.post.max_name_length
suhosin.post.max_totalname_length
suhosin.post.max_value_length
suhosin.post.max_vars
```

The same restrictions may apply to `suhosin.get.*`, `suhosin.cookie.*` and `suhosin.request.*`.
For debugging, it may be useful to put Suhosin into simulation mode and check log messages:

```
suhosin.simulation=1
```